# Is there a name for this kind of subgroup?

Tags: abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group, $H\subset G$ a subgroup such that if $nx\in H$ for $n\in \bf{Z}$ and $x\in G$ then $x\in H$. Is there a name for subgroups of abelian groups $H$ with this property?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your quantifiers? Do you mean 'if there's any $n$ such that $nx\in H$ then $x\in H$'? As things stand it reads like 'if for all $n$ and $x$, $nx\in H$, then $x\in H$', which is trivially true (just take $n=1$...)

Comment: Yeah, changed. The other meaning would always be true of course :P.

Comment: I don't know of a name, but a good guess might be "radical subgroup", inspired by the radical ideals of a ring.

Comment: For a related (but different) notion see [divisible group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group).

Comment: I found this https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/divisible+group